# How to perform full text search on a gin postgres index in doctrine 2.2?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, full-text-search, gwt-gin

Is there a simple way of doing this in doctrine, or am I going to have to do a native sql query? If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Any custom DQL function out there I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick answer is, no.  There is not a "simple way" of doing this.

You need to use Doctrine Native SQL which can be found [here](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html?highlight=native%20sql).  This will allow you to map the results into usable entities like you're used to while using database specific things.

You could also use a DQL user defined function, described [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html).  This is probably the "correct" way.